# call php function from JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to invoke a php function from JS.
php function:

```
function sayHi(){
debug_to_console("test");
}
```

I am running my site on local server so my address is like this:
http://localhost:8888/

Comment: You must use AJAX for this.

Comment: *sigh* Nonono. PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser. Javascript runs after.

Comment: As @JayBlanchard said, you will need to make an AJAX call to execute a PHP script via javascript. Most common JS libraries have simple wrapper functions to make AJAX calls. For example, [jquery has an AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).